# Write the code necessary to count the number of perfect squares whose value is less than h , starting with 1 .

Tags: integer-programming

Assume there is a variable , h already associated with a positive integer value. Write the code necessary to count the number of perfect squares whose value is less than h , starting with 1 . (A perfect square is an integer like 9 , 16 , 25 , 36 that is equal to the square of another integer (in this case 3*3 , 4*4 , 5*5 , 6*6 respectively).) Assign the sum you compute to a variable  q For example, if h is 19 , you would assign 4 to q because there are perfect squares (starting with 1 ) that are less than h are: 1 , 4 , 9 , 16 .

This is what I have so far, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

> q = 0
>
> > sqrt = int(h ** 0.5)
>
> if sqrt != h:
>
> > h += 1
>
> for i in range(1, sqrt):
>
> > q += 1

Comment: just calculate the value of floor(sqrt(h)).

Comment: Hint: int(h**0.5) *is* the number of perfect squares less than or equal to h.

Comment: Note that in general, `for i in range(1, n): q += 1` is identical to `q += n`.

Comment: You were probably meant to do this without using square roots; which make it trivial.  Instead, try incrementing the value of $q$ from $0$ while $q\ast q$ is less than or equal to $h$.

Answer (score 1):

```
main:  
  q=-1  
  s=0  
  WHILE(s$\lt$h)  
    q=q+1  
    s=s+2*q+1  
    WEND  
    PRINT q  
END
```

Comment: That's a nice, efficient, algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> `q = 0`
>
> `sqrt = int(h ** 0.5)`
>
> `if sqrt != h:`
>
> > `h += 1`
>
> `for i in range(1, sqrt):`
>
> > `q += 1`

This is bloated code.

- Why are you incrementing `h`?
- Why are you using a *for loop* to increment `q`?